# Netbeans: accessing static field - Replace with Class reference

Tags: java, netbeans, static, static-members

In my code I have this line:

```
private static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

and then I defined my setter function like this

```
public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

And NetBeans complains `Accessing static field items, replace with class reference?`

If I would replace this call with class reference like `MyClass.items = items;` it wouldn't be propagated into current object, isn't it?

Comment: An instance method that sets a static property.. Might want to refactor that piece :p. If you want to access the object' instance of `items` you would have to remove the static modifier.

Comment: so it's not possible to change value of static class member within class instance?

Comment: You can but why not make a static method for it as well?

Comment: I have static accessor method, should be setter static as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static variable is never "propagated" into the "current" object.

It is static, bound to the class. It lives even without an instance of the class, so there is no need to "propagate" it.

Btw: I would change the name of the method parameter, it is confusing to have the same name twice inside a method (and you wouldn't need the this if the parameter wasn't named like the static variable:

```
public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
    items = itemList;
}
```

Comment: so if I change static member value, it will be changed accross all my application?

Comment: Yes, that's the nature of a static variable

Comment: OK, Thanks a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2):

Well once you have declared a member in your class as `static` then it belongs to the class.
That is it will be defined only once when the first object instance is created. That is will be stored in the stack of the class.
 Rest all the instances of the class will share the member variable.
When a non-static variable is declared, whenever we create the object for that class a separate memory will be allocated for that variable, which will be specific to that instance.

In this case the `private static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();`

is the member variable of the class. Although you can access the variable using `this` but it creates a confusion. `this` is used in case of instance variable whereas static member variables are accessed through the Class name itself.
I hope this clears the doubt.

Comment: `That is it will be defined only once when the first object instance is created` this is not right, from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html `Any object can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.` isn't it? but rest of your answer is good, thanks

Comment: @Merek Sebera: Will each of the object instance have separate momory allocation for the static variable??? What I wanted to say was once the class is loaded into the JVM the memory of the static variable will be allocated just once.

Comment: no There will be only one instance shared between all interested classes. And all of them will access the same memory location. But yes, your pov is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want `items` to be static. A static property means that the variable is sort of global.

If you want each object to have their own instance of `items` you'll have to remove the `static` modifier.

Comment: no, I need it to be static. Thats exactly because I need to replace `global variable` behavior

Comment: If you need to replace global variable behavior, static variables are **not** the way to go.

Comment: and what is better way than? what kind of shared object should I use?

Comment: @Marek what do you need the shared object for? Are you positive you need the instance to be spread over a bunch of classes?

Comment: Yes, I have static accessor method in same class and other classes depends on value of this static object

Comment: The best solution would probably be to change your `setItems` method to be static and change the content of the method to: `MyClass.items = items`. This way netbeans'll stop complaining and you don't have to create an instance to modify the static value.